# How to make a property of an object always have the same value as another

Tags: javascript

I have the following Object

```
{
   a: "123"
   b: "$a"
}
```

`b` should always have the value of `a`.

Any idea of how I can make it with JavaScript?

Comment: why? the value of a is already set in the...value of a.

Comment: I doubt you have that JSON 'object' as it's an Array and not a valid one. Did you mean `{ "a": "123", "b":"$a" }`. Also JS objects  and JSON are not the same.

Comment: If you're asking how you would create such an object initializer in JavaScript, the answer is that you cannot.

Comment: didnt get you well. In this example if i type myobject.b, i should get 123 back which is the value of a. And if a change to 456, b should also then be 456.

Comment: Why should you that if you can use myobject.a?

Comment: @George and Pointy are correct, that is not an JSON but an array, and there is no way you can achieve that you want to do in JSON.
Only thing you can do is create a function that returns the JSON object in the way you want

Comment: @George you are right. It is in fact an js object. But still can formate it to JSON if i have to

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte how do you mean "in the way i want". could i achieve it with a correct JSON?

Comment: @Aline with "in the way you want" I mean having the second property of the object pointing to the first one. I'm curious about why you should need this since you already have the value of "a" on the property "a" why do you need a second property object with the same value?

Comment: @Nina Scholz just answer what I was trying to say, having an object with a function that returns the value of the other property, but as I said, I still do not understand why you cannot use "a" instead.

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte it is a long story. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) method for the property `b` with an object.

```js
var obj = {
    a: "123",
    get b() {
        return this.a;
    }
};

console.log(obj.b);
```

Otherwise, you are looking for an ES6 feature, [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

> The `Proxy` object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

Then take the `prop` and check if the value contains a `$` and return this value of this property.

```js
var obj = { a: "123", b: "$a" },
    p = new Proxy(obj, {
        get: function(target, prop) {
            return target[prop][0] === '$' ? target[target[prop].slice(1)] : target[prop];
        }
    });

console.log(p.b);
```

Comment: thank you very much. Your solution was excately, what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're meaning a real JavaScript object you can do this with a getter and a setter via [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Custom_Setters_and_Getters).

Answer (score -1):

Or you can create a "class"

```
    var obj= new function()
    {
    this.a=1212,
    this.b=this.a

    }
console.log(obj.b)
```